# Celery Flower access from remote machine

Tags: ssh, celery, tunnel, flower

I use Celery and Flower on a remote machine and connect to the local via SSH Tunnels (on Mac OS, Core Tunnel). My Flower app is started and I can CURL it from the remote machine:

> curl http://localhost:5555.

The tunnel is the following:

> ssh -L 127.0.0.1:10002:flower_server:5555 -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -o ServerAliveInterval=15 -o ServerAliveCountMax=3 login@tunnel_server

Thus, I expected that if I execute http://localhost:10002, the Flower instance from the remote machine will be displayed in my local browser. But instead, I return the ERR_CONNECTION_RESET exception. When I tried to execute CURL http://localhost:10002 from the local machine it returns

> Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

I don't have a clue what's wrong. Maybe someone had the same/similar issue?

Comment: I've not seen that syntax used to start a tunnel. The syntax I've used is `ssh -L LOCAL_PORT:DESTINATION_HOST:DESTINATION_PORT -N SSH_SERVER` It seems maybe the tunnel command is incorrect? To get your local port 10002 to forward to remote port 5555,  try: `ssh -L 10002:my_flower_server:5555 -N ssh_tunnel_server`. You may also be dropping the ssh connection somehow, so make sure you're keeping the window you run the command in open.

Comment: @sytech, thank you for your reasonable suggestions! 
My tunnel code looks like:
`ssh -L 127.0.0.1:10002:<flower_server>:5555 -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -o ServerAliveInterval=15 -o ServerAliveCountMax=3 <tunnel_server>` (I use Core Tunnel and everything was OK, until this Flower...). 

I added -N as you suggested, but it didn't help. 

Flower is running on the remote machine, but I still can't access it from the local. 

Now the error is: `channel 2: open failed: connect failed: No route to host`

Comment: And I checked, I'm keeping the connection.

Comment: @sytech, I user your ssh string: `ssh -L 10002:my_flower_server:5555 -N ssh_tunnel_server` with `-v -v -v`. The logs are the following:
`debug1: Connection to port 10002 forwarding to FLOWER_SERVER port 5555 requested.
debug2: fd 10 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: fd 10 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 2: new [direct-tcpip]
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug3: receive packet: type 92
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: No route to host`

Comment: Probably the issue is in Redis (it's Celery backend). Flower requires Redis. And I can connect to Redis from the remote machine, but I can't connect to it from the local. But I don't know how to fix it...

Comment: have you tried https://<remote_ip>:5555. `localhost` is your local machine and note remote. but of cause it will say localhost when you are looking from the remote machine :)